# Is there a way to export an object to Unity 3D while keeping any applied textures?

Tags: export, uv, external-applications, unity

I exported a `.fbx` file to Unity 3D, but it retained none of the applied textures.

Is there a way to create a textured model in Blender and export it into Unity while retaining the textures, without having to export my UV layout and retexture it again within Unity?

Comment: normally the uv-layouts are exported in the file, when in unity, you can open the material editor and drag the texture to the model

Comment: http://www.edy.es/dev/docs/materials-and-textures-from-blender-to-unity-3d/ Goes into some explanation about how materials between blender and Unity work. (note, the link to some time to load for me)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Textures and diffuse colors are not assigned automatically.** You have to manually assign them by dragging the texture onto the mesh in the Scene View in Unity

You don't have to export to `.fbx`, Unity supports `.blend`. To import a file into Unity,

- Right-click in the Projects pane, choose *'Import new Asset'*, and navigate to the file
- Move the `.blend` file into your project's Asset folder

You can read more [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-ImportObjectsFrom3DApps.html#Blender).

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of, but you can simply drop the texture on the object once it's in Unity. I did a tutorial on this if you want to watch it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J7Bncm2KGMo

(basically put the blend in your Unity folder and drop the image on the object's material)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean materials or textures?

For materials->

This depends on the material type but the most compatible is Blender Internal and transfer of diffuse and normal maps is possible.

When exporting from Blender set to copy in fbx exporter and select pack. This should include all the textures in the fbx file

In Unity make sure the fbx import uses the by material name recursive up setting.