# Export a file with textures to Unity?

Tags: export, unity

How can I export my blender file to unity so it saves all materials and textures?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/9184/599, http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/306/599, and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/9215/599.

Comment: i did a was written in the secnd link: import new asset, got to my blen file. but when I try to place it in the scene it isn't letting me