# UV unwrap doesn't show up in Object Mode?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, uv, unity

I know that this is a usual question and might already have an answer online, but I am stuck at UV unwrapping for a lot of time already and i want to explain my issue in detail.

I want to add textures from an image onto a few cubic meshes i have, mostly the front face. I unwrapped the cube in blender and added a image to and it looks good in the texture window, but as soon as i enter object mode or rendered the image is no more and the cube is showing the material only and not the image. I have already assigned the image texture with UV coordinates to the cube still it doesn't show up on object mode. Please help me..

Comment: Are you using BI or cycles? Is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Comment: Hey i can get the image in my object mode now, but when i switch to solid view it disappears again.
texture view -http://postimg.org/image/72mubr5yd/
Solid view -http://postimg.org/image/pwd8mhtk5/

Comment: Solid view doesn't display textures by default, use textured view, material view, rendered view, or enable *Textured solid* in *3D view > Properties region (N) > Shading*.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much. I can now atleast see it in solid view, but how can i ensure it will show up if i import it into unity 3d.

Comment: If you got it this far, it should be exported okay. The rest is on unity's end, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/306/599.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make a UV Mapped image appear in Object Mode, I found it was necessary to both:

- Set the Viewport Shading mode (The button just to the right of the Edit/Object mode selector in 3D View) to "Texture Mode"
- Set Properties -> Shading (game_settings.material_mode) to GLSL (OpenGL Shading Language)