# .blend files not importing into unity

Tags: export, unity, blend-files

So I for the past week or so I have been having extreme difficulty trying to import .blend file that I made into unity. When I either drag or import the .blend file into unity I automatically get a message saying "Blender has stopped working", as if the blender was even running to begin with,which it was not. Also in unity in the error bar on the bottom of the window I get the message blender could not convert the .blend file to FBX file. The only way I found to work around this,that only partially works, is to export the .blend as a .obj, but this will not work if your .blend file has multiple objects. I'm posting this to both the unity stack exchange and the blender stack exchange as either program could be at fault. I would appreciate any help I get get immensely, as this problem has been one of the most frustrating problems to date.

Thanks, Nova

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to export an object to Unity 3D while keeping any applied textures?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/306/is-there-a-way-to-export-an-object-to-unity-3d-while-keeping-any-applied-texture)

Comment: Can you upload your model? Does happen with all models? If so try reinstalling blender, and make sure no third party addons are breaking this.

Comment: No It's nothing to do with textures, I used to be able to just drop .blend files into unity just fine, but I got a  new computer installed blender and unity and this is happening

Comment: Roll back to 2.76. There is something wrong with communication Blender 2.77 <-> Unity

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion it worked, I'm surprised that not many other people have reported this problem.