# How to modify a model for Unity?

Tags: texturing, uv

I made the model in blender 2.77(a soccer room locker). The main problem is with the texture, it's textures aren't imported. I want to know how to do that, exporting UV maps and using them in unity. i just don't know how to do it. Can anyone help? Please be a bit detailed.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take a few moments to take the [tour](http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour), and to review the [help pages](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help), particularly the sections on asking questions. Do your textures show up on the object(s) in Blender before you try to export them? Are you sure that you are following the protocols established by Unity for import? More information, such as screenshots and an uploads (to <http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/>) of a copy of a blend file might help us give you a better answer.

Comment: UVs are imported, you just need to set up materials and textures in Unity separately from Blender, that's how it's intended.

Comment: Probably you are looking to drop the texture (in unity, find it in the file structure) right onto the material's "Albedo" setting (right onto the square next to it).  I have found that Unity doesn't want to import texture properly, but solid colors work fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to export an object to Unity 3D while keeping any applied textures?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/306/is-there-a-way-to-export-an-object-to-unity-3d-while-keeping-any-applied-texture)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, i'll be as detailed as possible.

Okay so first, create your model, for demonstration purposes, I have a cube.

[image: Cube]

After creating your model, select all the faces in edit mode and press <kbd>U</kbd> then select whatever option is best for you. I used the normal "Unwrap".

[image: Unwrapping]

After that, create your texture, and apply it to the model, to do that, click New or Open in the UV/Image editor (while in edit mode and with your models faces selected).

I clicked new and in the menu it opens I set the image from Blank to Color grid.

[image: Creating the texture]

Now that that's all done, we've got our texture, time to save it. Do that by clicking Image (It should have a little * at the end of it) and click "Save As Image", and select your location, can be anywhere.

[image: Saving the texture]
(set the render view to Textured to see what it looks like)

And now, finally save the model as well. You should use a .blend as the format, but some other formats may work too, but for the sake of a tutorial, you should use .blend.

Alright, so next, drag your model into the Project in Unity, do that by simply dragging and dropping the file from the location you saved it to, into Unity's Project window.

[image: Putting the model in there]

And now, drag it into the Hierarchy, it should be in the scene now.

[image: Putting the model in there 2.0]

Nice, we've got a model imported into unity now. Okay so now we do the dragging and dropping of the texture in the project window as well, like we did with the model.

After that's put into the Project window alike the model, we will then drag it onto the object.

[image: And we're done!]

Nice, we've got our model all textured and ready to go, and all set up. And now time to make some scripts so it does something. :)

Good luck!

[image: What it finally looks like]

Comment: thanks for taking up your time to write this, but i still have a problem, unwrapping the soccer locker, should i do all of the planks in it separately by marking seams? and how do i add texture afterwards? (because whenever i try to put texture, it turns out blurred because it is too big, or too small or something).

Comment: Upload your .blend using blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and i'll take a look at it for you so i can fully understand your problem. :P

Comment: here @Luka [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1446" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1446/)